# Can I get an image's file size and mime-type via JavaScript (FireFox/Gecko/Mozilla only)

Tags: javascript, firefox, image, gecko

Can I get an image's file size and mime-type via JavaScript. I am writing a script for inspecting all images in a document. I will run the script in FireFox only so a solution  specific to FireFox (undocumented/non-standard/otherwise) is perfectly acceptable. I can use jQuery if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make a `HEAD` request with XHR which will tell you the file size, provided these images are on your domain.

Comment: _provided these images are on your domain_... unfortunately, that's not the case.

Comment: @Salman In that case, you will need to proxy through a server side language (which can figure out the mime and filesize anyway).

Comment: I can do this via php I guess.

Answer (score 3):

you can do it through HTTP head request

```
       var request;
        request = $.ajax({
                  type: "HEAD",
                  url: 'your image url',
                  success: function () {
                  alert("Size is " + request.getResponseHeader("Content-Length"));
                  alert("Type is " + request.getResponseHeader("Content-Type"));
                  }
               });
```