# Client side header information

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a web application build on PHP that (does some processing and) displays images hosted on external servers.  Some of these images (i.e. from Flickr) when they are deleted, leave a redirect behind that points to a "Missing Image" gif or something equivalent.

By using the `get_headers()` function in php on each image, I was able to check server-side if an image was deleted or not (for example, by checking if the `Content-Type` was `image/gif` instead of `image/jpg`, on Flickr images).

The problem is that each page returns 20-100 images on average (sometimes even more), and `get_headers()` requires on average 0.3-0.5s for each image, thus making the wait time for the user too long.

I was wondering if this check could be done client-side, using javascript.  The user will be waiting for the images to load (as with any page), I will be checking the images if they are valid, and set display property to none on the missing ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`curl_multi_exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php) to check multiple URLs at once. If you use the following cURL options:

```
CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION = FALSE
CURLOPT_NOBODY = TRUE
CURLOPT_HEADER = TRUE
```

...this will prevent the following of redirects. You can then use this information (whether the response is a redirect or not, see `CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE` in [`curl_get_info()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php)) to determine whether the file exists. By using `curl_multi_exec()` you will perform multiple checks at once, which should drastically reduce the page load time.

Comment: `curl_multi_exec()` reduces the check to ~0.5sec for 24 images (probably for more as well since is run concurrently) which is acceptable for the nature of the application, so it works like a charm. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method to determine the image type but it may cause some extra traffic to your servers.

```
var request;
    request = $.ajax({
              type: "HEAD",
              url: 'your image url',
              success: function () {
              alert("Size is " + request.getResponseHeader("Content-Length"));
              alert("Type is " + request.getResponseHeader("Content-Type"));
              }
           });
```

Found here: [Can I get an image's file size and mime-type via JavaScript (FireFox/Gecko/Mozilla only)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5456245/can-i-get-an-images-file-size-and-mime-type-via-javascript-firefox-gecko-mozil)

Comment: Good point, I totally forgot I could have used AJAX to forward the queries back to my server. I 'll keep that in mind for similar things in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use javascript, for example Ajax to make your requests to a PHP program.

However, instead of using get_headers (), you might come better to use this feature: http://es.php.net/manual/es/function.file-exists.php#85246

Regards!